# Combining multiple lines of SQL response into a single line and renaming values

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I have a query, for example...

```
SELECT a.order_number, b.state
from tableone a
tabletwo b
WHERE
1=1
AND a.id = b.id
AND a.order_number = '12345';
```

This outputs:

```
order_number    state
12345             CA
12345             AZ
12345             NY
```

I'm looking instead of have this return a concatenated line so I can keep this result to a single line.

```
order_number       state
12345                 CA,AZ,NY
```

So I built this:

```
SELECT
a.order_number, 
LISTAGG(b.state, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.order_number) AS states
from tableone a
tabletwo b
WHERE
1=1
AND a.id = b.id
AND a.order_number = '12345'
GROUP BY a.order_number;
```

Now - my question is - how do I assign values to these states?  There are only 3 - CA, AZ, and NY, where CA = 1, AZ = 2, and NY = 3.  I either have to do this logic to sync up with another app that's using these numerical values to represent states here in the SQL, or in another system on the backend, and I'd prefer to do it here if possible...

I'd like my output to look like this:

```
order_number       state
12345                 1,2,3
```

Comment: CA is always 1, AZ is always 2, and NY is always 3.  If NY exists, I want to replace it with 3.  If CA exists, I want to replace it with 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're having to hard-code the conversion and there is no look-up table to convert state codes to numbers, you can just use a case expression:

```
CASE b.state WHEN 'CA' THEN 1 WHEN 'AZ' THEN 2 WHEN 'NY' THEN 3 END
```

which you can use inside the `LISTAGG()` call:

```
SELECT
  a.order_number, 
  LISTAGG(CASE b.state WHEN 'CA' THEN 1 WHEN 'AZ' THEN 2 WHEN 'NY' THEN 3 END, ',')
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.order_number) AS states
FROM tableone a
JOIN tabletwo b
ON a.id = b.id
WHERE
1=1
AND a.order_number = '12345'
GROUP BY a.order_number;    

ORDER_NUMBER STATES              
------------ --------------------
12345        1,2,3
```

Incidentally, I've taken the liberty of switching to proper join syntax. Also the `order by` clause isn't really doing anything at the moment as you're grouping by that value, so it's always the same within the group; if the order matters then you need to change that - possibly to the same case expression.